# tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension under iOS 13 and iPhone 11 Pro simulator leads to an endless update subviews loop

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-simulator, ios13

I'm updating an existing app to iOS 13. If I test the app using an iPhone 11 Pro (Max) simulator the following line leads to an endless layout update cycle:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

In combination with later call of:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

With iOS 12 or a non "Pro" iPhone the app works as expected.

Does anybody have this behavior, too? What could be a possible issue for that behavior?

Comment: did you set `estimatedRowHeight` value for that table?

Comment: Yes. ```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
```

Comment: weird i can't reproduce your issue

Comment: @ReinierMelian on one hand, this is great, on the other hand, krmpf. thanks for testing it!

Comment: Where you are reloading tableview?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all this was not table view related. It was a false glue. It seems that on an iPhone 11 Pro simulator, the `layoutSubviews` method gets a lot more often called. I fixed an issue in this method of an embedded view which was not an "error" in prior iOS Versions and devices.

Nevertheless, it was my mistake.